# How to check if a CheckButton is active or not in pygtk2.0?

Tags: python, gtk

I am wondering what is the method that tells me whether a box is sensitive (active or not)?

I tried `.get_sensitive()` but it seems that this is not a `gtk.CheckButton` attribute. Any help?

- This is different than `set_sensitive()` which I believe sets a checkbutton to be OFF or ON, also different from `.set_sensitive()`, which checks or unchecks the box.

Comment: Is it active as in checked or unchecked or sensitive as in not disabled?

Comment: Sensitive as in not disabled

Comment: Did you know that Gtk2 and pygtk are deprecated? Please switch to Gtk3 and gi-repository.

Comment: In Gtk3, `sensitive` is indeed whether the checkbutton can be clicked or not, and `active` is whether the checkbutton is _checked_ or not.